# Show that the PDE $v_t = v_{xx} + av_{x}$ is well posed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let the function $v(x,t)$ solve the PDE
$$
v_t = v_{xx} + av_{x}, \qquad t \geq 0, \quad x \in [0,1],
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, with an initial condition (i.c.) for $t = 0$ and zero Dirichlet boundary conditions.

> In the sense of the standard $L_2[0,1]$ norm, is this problem
> well-posed?

My attempt:

Separate variables by writing $v(x,t) = E(t)g(x)$. Provided that the i.c. $g(x)$ possesses a Fourier series expansion for $x \in [0,1]$:
$$g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m \sin m\pi x$$

and, by substituting it into our PDE, the full solution can then be written as
$$v(x,t) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m \exp\left(-m^2\pi^2+am\pi\frac{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\cos m\pi x}{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\sin m\pi x}\right)\sin m\pi x.$$
Now
$$\vert v(x,t)\vert^2 = \int_0^1 \vert v(t,x)\vert^2 dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m \exp\left(-2m^2\pi^2+2am\pi\frac{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\cos m\pi x}{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\sin m\pi x}\right), $$
where we have used the fact that
$$\int_0^1 \sin m\pi x \sin j\pi x dx$$
is only non-zero (and $=1/2$) when $j = m$. To demonstrate well-posedness, I want to try and show that $\vert E(t) \vert^2 \leq C$ uniformly for all $t$. This means we have to put a bound on the exponentials in our sum. The first term is promising, the second term with the messy looking fraction is less so.

**Questions:**

> Is my approach so far correct (i.e. no mistakes)?

> How do I finish my argument to show well-posedness?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Here's another method. Suppose $u(t,x)$ solves the heat equation:
$$(\partial_t-\partial_x^2)u=0\tag{1}$$
Then, it is easy to show that $v(t,x):=u(t,x+at)$ solves the equation in the question:
$$(\partial_t-\partial_x^2-a\partial_x)v=0\tag{2}$$
In other words, if one seeks to solve the IVP $(2)$ with the initial data $v(0,x)=\varphi(x)$ and with Dirichlet BCs $v(t,0)=v(t,1)=0$ then an equivalent problem is to solve $(1)$ with the initial data $u(0,x)=\varphi(x)$ and with BCs $u(t,at)=u(t,1+at)=0$. Now perhaps we can use known well-posedness results of the heat equation.

Comment: If you know that the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ is well-pose the change of coordinates $x,t\to \xi,t$ where $\xi = x+at$ transforms $u_t = u_{xx} + au_x$ to $u_t = u_{\xi \xi}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question being to prove the well-posedness in $L^2$ of the equation, we could avoid explicit computation of solution and use a priori estimates. Indeed if $v$ solves the equation, multiplying it by $v$ and integrating on $[0,1]$ gives:
$$\int_0^1 v_t v dx -\int_0^1 v_{xx} v dx - a\int_0^1 v_x v dx =0.$$
which upon integration by parts in the second integral is:
$$\int_0^1 \frac12 (v^2)_t dx +\int_0^1 v_x^2 dx+\left[v_x v\right]_0^1 - a\int_0^1 \frac12 (v^2)_x dx =0.$$
The bracket and the last integral are zero from homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Thus
$$\frac{d\;}{dt}\int_0^1 v^2 dx+\int_0^1 v_x^2 dx=0$$
which gives upon time integration:
$$\|v(t)\|_{L^2}\le\|v(0)\|_{L^2}\qquad\forall t\in \mathbb{R}^+.$$
From the linearity of the equation, this shows that the solution depends continuously on the initial condition, ie the problem is well-posed.